# NiceEditor не сохраняется стилизованный текст в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Не получается используя NiceEditor сохранить отредактированный текст в БД. Помогите! Код формы:

```
<form method="post" action="functions.php">               
<script type="text/javascript">
                    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
                      var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
                      myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
                      myNicEditor.addInstance('myInstance1');

                      });
                </script>
                <div id="myNicPanel" style="width: 700px;"></div>
                <textarea name="text_notes" id="myInstance1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;">
                    Ваш текст...
                </textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="submit"  value="Добавить" name="add_notes"/>
                </form>
```

Comment: Може Вы остальной код покажете? А то с метками php и mysql у Вас нет ни того, ни другого.

Answer (score 0):

Может потому, что форма отправляет данные из `textarea`, а вся магия визуализации происходит в `<div id="myNicPanel" />` ?

Берите `document.querySelector('#myNicPanel').innerHTML`  и отправляйте его аяксом или вставляйте еще в какой-то textarea и отправляйте классическим методом.

Ну и  на стороне сервера не забывайте про экранирование кавычек (и не только) перед записью в бд.